# Multiple ToMany for 1 table greenDAO

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

I have 2 models like this:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    Long _id;

    String name;

    @ToMany(referencedJoinProperty = "bookId")
    List<Chapter> chapters1;

    @ToMany(referencedJoinProperty = "bookId")
    List<Chapter> chapters2;
}


@Entity
public class Chapter {

    @Id
    Long _id;

    String name;
    int type;
    long bookId;
    @ToOne(joinProperty = "bookId")
    Book book;
}
```

There are 2 type of chapter type1 and 2, currently, when I get chapters1, greenDAO return all type1 and 2, how can I get only type1 or 2 in class Book?

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this query

```
Select from Chapter where type = [1 or 2]
```

Comment: I know that I can write a query like that, but I want to retrieve expected result by greenDAO generated code. Is there any way to do this?